# How do I set a gradle version in Github CI

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, github-actions

Our project specifically uses some deprecated features and Kotlin so we have to use Gradle 6.1.1. On GitHub, the android studio build action automatically uses Gradle 7.0, how can we change this?

Our code is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/CMS-robotics/ftc17191_2021-2022)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to older version by updating your wrapper:

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=6.1.1
```

so it would be:

```yaml
    - name: Build with Gradle
      run: | 
         ./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=6.1.1
         ./gradlew build
```